# QProcess causes "R6016 - not enough space for thread data"

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

Launching ipconfig using `QProcess` causes a crash with an error dialog

> Runtime error!
>
> c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ipconfig.exe
>
> R6016
>
> - not enough space for thread data

on some machines (it is not everywhere that the problem occurs), see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQjhW.jpg).

Am I incorrectly using `QProcess`?

I tested in:

- Windows 7 64ibt
- Windows 8/10

Using:

- QT5.8.0
- Mingw 5.3 32bit

Minimal code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QRegExp>
#include <QDebug>

QProcess *checkGateway;

void detectGateway() {
    //Start ipconfig
    QProcess* proc = new QProcess();
    QObject::connect(proc, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int)>(&QProcess::finished), [proc](int exitStatus) {
        Q_UNUSED(exitStatus);

        /* parse */

        int testAfter = 1000; //1 sec

        QRegExp rx("gateway[^\\r\\n]+(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})");
        rx.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);

        const QString getResp = proc->readAll();

        if (rx.indexIn(getResp) > -1) {
            qDebug() << "Gateway:" << rx.cap(1);
            testAfter = 5000; //5 sec
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Not found";
        }

        QTimer::singleShot(testAfter, [](){
            detectGateway();
        });

        /* parse */

    });
    proc->start("ipconfig");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget w;

    detectGateway();

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You are creating many processes recursively, you have tried to make your QProcess object static.

Comment: You appear to be creating a new `QProcess` at regular'ish intervals (either 1s or 5s) without ever deleting the finished `QProcess` `proc` -- I think.

Comment: @G.M So I will try to create a new variable every cycle and use "deleteLater" in the old one (within the scope of the function), so that I can return with the result. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to create those processes all anew. Reuse them.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks, but I'm reusing it `QProcess *checkGateway`, Or did not I get something?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I proposed?